Python Automation for Manual Data Entry - Can't Identify Fields
I get accounting data from one software. I extract rows with errors. I create new rows (so they alternate) with the correct data. Then I go into a different software & manually type all this crap back out. Should be easy to automate.
I successfully wrote a Python script to log into the web app, contingency for needing to wait for a MFA. It navigates to the data entry page successfully, but then fails to identify any of the data entry fields; timing out & spitting back the same errors. I've added some "debugging" & even had a source.html file created to help troubleshoot. This is the script I'm using
Python Script:
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException, ElementNotInteractableException

# Initialize Chrome WebDriver using WebDriver Manager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

# Navigate to the login page
driver.get('starting url')

# Locate the input fields and enter credentials
cruzid_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'j_username')
password_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'j_password')

# Enter your credentials
cruzid_field.send_keys('actual username')
password_field.send_keys('actual password')

# Click the login button
login_button = driver.find_element(By.NAME, '_eventId_proceed')
login_button.click()

# After successful login, locate the search input field and enter the search term
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.url_contains('next url'))
    print("Logged in successfully!")

    # Locate the search input field using its ID
    search_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'search-landing'))
    )
    search_field.send_keys('data entry code')

    # Simulate pressing Enter to initiate the search
    search_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    # Switch to the iframe containing the content
    print("Switching to iframe")
    iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'bannerHS'))
    )
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    print("Switched to iframe")

    # Verify the current context is the iframe
    current_frame = driver.execute_script("return self.name")
    print(f"Current iframe context: {current_frame}")

    # Wait for the tab-container element to be present after search (up to 120 seconds)
    print("Waiting for the tab-container element to be present")
    tab_container = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'tab-container'))
    )
    print("Tab-container element is present, search completed!")

    # Attempt to locate the "Go" button using ID
    print("Attempting to locate the Go button by ID")
    go_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'frames6'))
    )
    go_button.click()
    print("Go button clicked successfully!")

    # Wait for the pnlFgbjvch1Canvas element to appear
    print("Waiting for pnlFgbjvch1Canvas element to be present")
    pnl_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'pnlFgbjvch1Canvas'))
    )
    print("pnlFgbjvch1Canvas element is present")

    # Adding a brief delay to ensure the element is ready for interaction
    time.sleep(2)

    ***# Pause for manual date and document total entry*** PROBLEM 1
    input("Please enter the transaction date and document total manually, then press Enter to continue...")

    *# Wait for the specific div elements to be present* PROBLEM 2
    print("Waiting for the view div element to be present")
    view_div = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'view_16d82cc3-d839-4611-aaf5-6c06ddf7b162'))
    )
    print("View div element is present")

    print("Waiting for the collapsible panel (rect145) to be present")
    collapsible_panel = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'rect145'))
    )
    print("Collapsible panel (rect145) is present")

    # Perform the tab action to move to the next field
    print("Performing tab action")
    body = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body')
    body.send_keys(Keys.TAB)

    print("Waiting for the frames29 panel to be present")
    frames_panel = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'frames29'))
    )
    print("Frames29 panel is present")

    # Click the input field with ID inp:fgbjvcdRuclCode
    print("Locating the RUCL Code input field")
    rucl_code_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'inp:fgbjvcdRuclCode'))
    )
    rucl_code_input.click()
    print("RUCL Code input field clicked")

    # Read the 4-character code from the Excel file
    print("Reading the 4-character code from the Excel file")
    df = pd.read_excel('file/path')
    code = df.iloc[0, 0]
    print(f"Code read from Excel: {code}")

    # Enter the code into the input field
    print("Entering the code into the RUCL Code input field")
    rucl_code_input.send_keys(code)

    print("Complete")
    time.sleep(30)

except (TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException, ElementNotInteractableException) as e:
    print(f"Error occurred: {e}")

# Close the browser
driver.quit()



I replaced Problem 1 with the following to use XPATH to identify the field. The first time I ran it, it succeeded & tabbed to the next field. The second time I ran it; it failed. It timeout & was unable to identify & click into the transaction date field:

# Use a more robust XPath to locate the transaction date input field
    print("Locating the transaction date input field")
    transaction_date_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, '//input[contains(@id, "fgbjvchTransDate") and @name="fgbjvchTransDate"]'))
    )
    print("Transaction date input field located")

    # Ensure the element is visible and interactable
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.visibility_of(transaction_date_input)
    )
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable(transaction_date_input)
    )

    # Click into the transaction date input field
    print("Clicking the transaction date input field")
    transaction_date_input.click()

    # Perform the tab action
    print("Performing tab action")
    transaction_date_input.send_keys(Keys.TAB)




